# Docker: Gateway Connection Refused to other Docker Container/Compose file (Angular -> Nestjs)

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, angular-universal

I have two docker compose files.

1. Docker compose for my Angular Universal App:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  myproject:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/myproject/Dockerfile
      target: development-build
    command: yarn run dev:ssr
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - '4200:4200'
```

2. Docker Compose for my NestJs services

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/api/Dockerfile
      target: development-build
    command: npm run start:dev api
    env_file:
      - ./apps/api/.env
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
...
```

On my local machine:

- localhost:4200 is reachable and shows the angular app
- localhost:3000 is reachable and the api endpoints work

Inside my Angular App I proxy all api calls to localhost:3000 with my proxy conf:

```json
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

This works perfectly without docker.
But when I run both docker compose files on my machine, I get an ECONNREFUSED error:

```bash
[HPM] Proxy created: /api  -> http://localhost:3000
 | [HPM] Subscribed to http-proxy events: [ 'error', 'close' ]
 | ** Angular Universal Live Development Server is listening on http://localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200 **
 | [HPM] POST /api/auth/local/login -> http://localhost:3000
 | [HPM] Error occurred while proxying request localhost:4200/api/auth/local/login to http://localhost:3000/ [ECONNREFUSED] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

What am I missing to allow the angular app (node server) to reach outside to the other docker container over port 3000?

Thank you for looking at it!

Comment: In this call sequence, the browser (outside a container) tries to call `http://localhost:4200/api/...`, which matches a published `ports:` for the `myproject` container.  But once that container receives the message, it tries to make the outbound call to `localhost:3000`, which is the same container and not the other container.  See for example [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) which describes how to make connections between containers; also consider moving these two connected components into the same Compose file.